# Get Element Tree with Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml record within a larger xml file:

```
<Employee>
<id>999</id>
<fname>Tim</fname>
<lname>Boskin</lname>
</Employee>
```

I am attempting to get the fname and lname attributes via lxml and xpath in python. The following statement is not returning anything:

```
fname = root.xpath('.//Employee[@id="999"]/fname')
```

Every example I have found and attempted has yielded no results, what would be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`@id` selects value of the attribute named id.***

And this is why it goes wrong. Try this:

```
fname = root.xpath('//Employee[id/text()="999"]/fname')
```

Because there is no attribute named `id` within the `Employee` element, instead it is a child element of the `Employee` element. For more details on XPath axes read **[this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)**.

Comment: Ah, appreciate it. I was misunderstanding the xpath syntax.